# How to Remap the
Hardware Buttons On
Your Android Phone

Tags: hardware

I want my return hardware button (capacitive touch buttons) to turn into recent apps button. Please help me out. I don't use return button enough.

Comment: Is your device rooted? Otherwise, button remapping is (at least currently) not possible.

Comment: If rooted Xposed framework with Gravity Box module will do it.